# Null Exception in Flutter on Widget that seems to Print values

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, stream-provider

The problem is that I get an exception when I lunch my Application and I don't know why. It seems like it's trying to access a null variable. I've no idea where is the problem.

This is the code of Home class.

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();

  Home({super.key});


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<QuerySnapshot?>.value(
      value: DataBaseService().events,
      initialData: null,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.brown[300],
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Home Title"),
          elevation: 0.0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.brown[500],
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Icon(Icons.person),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                await _auth.signOut();
              },
              child: Icon(Icons.logout),
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: EventsList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here the code of EventsList class:

```
class _EventsListState extends State<EventsList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    final events = Provider.of<QuerySnapshot?>(context);
    print(events);
    for (var e in events!.docs) {
      final data = e.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      print(data['eventName']);
      print(data);
    }
    return Container();
  }
}
```

(If you notice ... I try to Print the data related to the user and it works. Really do not know why when I enter in EventsList() I've got the error.

I put also the DataBaseService class:

```
class DataBaseService {
  final String? userID;

  DataBaseService({this.userID});

  final CollectionReference eventsCollection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('event');

  Future updateUserData(String eventName, double cost, String age) async {
    return await eventsCollection
        .doc(userID)
        .set({'eventName': eventName, 'cost': cost, 'age': age});
  }

  Stream<QuerySnapshot>? get events {
    return eventsCollection.snapshots();
  }
}
```

And my Firestore Database:

[Here the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJzkD.png)

And also the image of the terminal (with the exception)
[The exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jwgrf.png)

I've searched for hours on sites, but any try did not worked.
Do you have and idea how to fit it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: In the line "final events = Provider.of<QuerySnapshot?>(context);"
you turn events into the type QuerySnapshot? - which can be null. But in the line "for (var e in events!.docs)" you declare that events would definitely NOT be null. Is this the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I removed the question mark and the exlamation point and the code now is:

```
class _EventsListState extends State<EventsList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //questa è la raccolta madre
    final events = Provider.of<QuerySnapshot>(context);
    print(events);
    for (var e in events.docs) {
      final data = e.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      print(data['eventName']);
      print(data);
    }
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Now I have this issue:
[new problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lte81.png)

It shouldn't happen because in the terminal I can see the value (the data) of events printed.

And ideas?
It's like the Provider doesn't match the documents that are stored in FireStore.

Thank you very much!

Comment: If your provider gives you a QuerySnapshot? and not a QuerySnapshot, you can't just drop the "?". Maybe just put the ? back where it was and then you check if your value is null, for example: add a line before your for loop: "if(events == null) return Container(child: Text('empty'));" After that null check, you can safely assume "events!.doc" - meaning: then it is safe to declare that events is NOT null. Does that help?

Comment: Could be an idea. The fact is that event shouldn't be null. I can see the Records of those documents in Firebase console. Furthermore, I can print the values of them. I really don't know why i says that the matching returns null.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).